# Apply function to each row in Torch

Tags: lua, row, apply, torch, elementwise-operations

I know that tensors have an `apply` method, but this only applies a function to each element. Is there an elegant way to do row-wise operations? For example, can I multiply each row by a different value?

Say

```
A =
  1 2 3
  4 5 6
  7 8 9
```

and

```
B =
  1
  2
  3
```

and I want to multiply each element in the `i`th row of A by the `i`th element of B to get

```
1 2 3
8 10 12
21 24 27
```

how would I do that?

Comment: You should take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123291/torch-apply-function-over-dimension

Answer (score 2):

See this link: [Torch - Apply function over dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123291/torch-apply-function-over-dimension)

(Thanks to Alexander Lutsenko for providing it. I just moved it to the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to [expand](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#result-expandresult-sizes) `B` as follow:

```
 1  1  1
 2  2  2
 3  3  3
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 3x3]
```

Then you can use [element-wise multiplication](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/maths.md#res-torchcmulres-tensor1-tensor2) directly:

```
local A = torch.Tensor{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
local B = torch.Tensor{1,2,3}
local C = A:cmul(B:view(3,1):expand(3,3))
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, there are a few different ways to do it for my example, but I was wondering if there was a general way to apply a function to each row. I think Alexander's comment answers my first question.

Answer (score 0):

It is linear algebra question.

Transpose(Transpose(A) * Diagonal matrix (1, 2, 3))

If you want to do it in col-wise then don't need transpose.