# Enumerate function in lua/torch

Tags: python, lua, torch

In python, we use `for i, _ in enumerate(wx):` where `wx` is a row matrix or table.
How can we use this in lua/torch. Any enumerate function?

Answer (score 1):

In Lua, you have [`pairs`](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#pdf-pairs) and [`ipairs`](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#pdf-ipairs):

> ```
> pairs (t)
> ```
>
> If `t` has a metamethod `__pairs`, calls it with `t` as argument and
>   returns the first three results from the call.
>
> Otherwise, returns three values: the `next` function, the table `t`,
>   and `nil`, so that the construction
>
> ```
> for k,v in pairs(t) do body end
> ```
>
> will iterate over all key–value pairs of table `t`.

You can also use [`next`](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#pdf-next), for creating your own custom enumeration:

> ```
> next (table [, index])
> ```
>
> Allows a program to traverse all fields of a table. Its first argument
>   is a table and its second argument is an index in this table. next
>   returns the next index of the table and its associated value. When
>   called with `nil` as its second argument, `next` returns an initial
>   index and its associated value. When called with the last index, or
>   with `nil` in an empty table, `next` returns **nil**. If the second
>   argument is absent, then it is interpreted as nil. In particular, you
>   can use `next(t)` to check whether a table is empty.
>
> The order in which the indices are enumerated is not specified, *even
>   for numeric indices*. (To traverse a table in numerical order, use a
>   numerical **for**.)
>
> The behavior of `next` is undefined if, during the traversal, you
>   assign any value to a non-existent field in the table. You may however
>   modify existing fields. In particular, you may clear existing fields.

Comment: @Sibi It'd be `a= { 1, 2, 3 }`

Comment: In Lua if you use table then it works `a={1,2,3} for i,v in ipairs(a) do print(i,v) end`

Comment: Why isn't it working when I declare `a=torch.rand(4,5)`? I need it to work for these types of `a`

Comment: `a` is not a table but a 2D tensor so use [`apply`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#applying-a-function-to-a-tensor) or convert it with `a:totable()`. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123291/torch-apply-function-over-dimension